# What's wrong with my oven?

Tags: oven

I have a Kenmore stove, model number 911-735-9180. My burners are working fine (they click to turn on) but my oven does not work. I push the bake setting and it does not heat up although my broiler works fine.

Comment: Is it a stove you're familiar with that has worked in the past? Just wondering if it's a question on using the stove or if it's developed a fault.

Comment: Gas or electric?

Comment: If was working before... call Sears?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a technical question about an appliance, not anything to do with cooking as per our guidelines.

Comment: @Cindy Kitchen equipment is the second bullet in the help center: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I do think questions like this will likely get better answers on http://diy.stackexchange.com/ though, since those folks often have more experience with major appliance repair than us.

Comment: Thanks @Jefromi. I was thinking that use or advice would be more in our scope than repair.

Answer (score 2):

- In the world of home appliances, a cooktop with an oven in a common cabinet is called a "Range".
- This is a Kenmore Gas Range model # 911.7359180
- Sears model #'s usually don't have - dashes/hyphens in them.
- There are only 3 or 4 parts that can fail.

#### Basic Gas Oven Troubleshooting:

1. Check the power, needs to be plugged in, standard 110vac outlet.
2. Check the Igniter, it's the most common oven part that fails. Does it glow?

   - NO = replace igniter $25
   - YES = can you smell/detect gas from oven pilot or burner? = replace igniter.
   - YES = but no gas smelled/detected. = bad gas valve.

May have 1 valve, combination safety & control OR
2 valves, separate safety & control.
Gas Valves start around $100.

CAUTION! If you are unsure of what you are doing, Hire a Professional! 
You and yours could die if repaired improperly.
www.appliancerepair.net  has a good general online guide covering all types of appliances. Ovens are at:  http://www.appliancerepair.net/oven-repair-6.html

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! A helpful user has fixed up the formatting in your answer. Your signature was also removed - your username's at the bottom anyway, and while we're fine with you advertising on your profile page, we'd rather the answers stick to answering the question.